Gradle failed sync Android studio
I'm trying to install and run Android studio on the latest version Jellyfish 2023.3.1 and I keep getting these error message.
First error message:
C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c-05cdfca4-d5e5-4635-9702-36fafef6018e -> C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c

Second error message
A build operation failed.
    Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c-05cdfca4-d5e5-4635-9702-36fafef6018e) to immutable location (C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c)
> Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c-05cdfca4-d5e5-4635-9702-36fafef6018e) to immutable location (C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.internal.operations.MultipleBuildOperationFailures: A build operation failed.
    Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c-05cdfca4-d5e5-4635-9702-36fafef6018e) to immutable location (C:\Users\jordy\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\f2cfbe96f4ea4bebc97720eee3299b1c)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.markFinished(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.waitForWorkToComplete(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue.waitForCompletion(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:107)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.executeInParallel(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.runAll(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ParallelResolveArtifactSet$VisitingSet.visit(ParallelResolveArtifactSet.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:297)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$600(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$3.run(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.visitArtifactsWithBuildOperation(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.access$300(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:75)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.lambda$visitArtifacts$0(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsUnmanagedWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$2.visitArtifacts(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.SelectedArtifactSet.visitFiles(SelectedArtifactSet.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.ResolutionBackedFileCollection.visitContents(ResolutionBackedFileCollection.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:361)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.UnionFileCollection.visitChildren(UnionFileCollection.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:113)


Give your gradle files to understand question with ease.

This is a bug in newer Gradle versions that is hopefully fixed in 8.9.
For the full story, please see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/28475#issuecomment-2162494662.
For the time being, downgrading to 8.5 should hopefully fix the build.

Hey man thank you so much it worked!

Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ;-)
